# Convert Binary data to Image

Tags: java, image, binary

```
         FileInputStream is;
    FileOutputStream out;
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    int readBytes = 0;

    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        out = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/gopir/Desktop/me1Copy.jpeg");
        while ((readBytes = is.read(data)) > 0) {
              out.write(data,0,readBytes);
            }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        is.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am just trying to convert image to binary and binary to image. Image to binary conversion works. To check the integrity, I just tried to convert binary data to image. It creates empty image file. What's wrong with this code?

Is there any other way to do this? I am not interested in using external jars such as apache common.

**EDIT**

This is how I create Binary file

```
                File imageFile = new File(pathName); // Any file Path
        BufferedInputStream bis = null; // To read the given file
        BufferedWriter bw = null; //To write the binary equivalent of the file contents
        String outputFile = "C:\\Users\\gopir\\Desktop\\file1.txt"; // output file name

        try {
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile)); //Output writer stream
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(imageFile)); // Input file reader stream
            int read;
            String text;
            while((read = bis.read()) != -1){ // read 
                text = Integer.toString(read,2); // convert to string
                while (text.length() < 8) { // if length less than 8, prepend 0's
                    text="0"+text;
                }
                bw.write(text); //write it to a file
            }
               bis.close();
                bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Please check your input file. I have tried your code Its working fine for me..

Comment: Please see the edit @Siva

Comment: Why are you converting integer to String

Comment: I am converting int to binary.

Comment: This code doesn't make much sense. Converting an image file to a binary file is useless: an image file **is** a binary file, as every file. What you're doing is converting the bytes contained in the image file to padded numbers written as text, and hope the binary representation of this text in your platform default encoding still represents the same image. What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: I am trying to implement [Las vegas randomized algo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Las_Vegas_algorithm). For which I need binary data. So I just wanted to try with image.

Comment: Every data is binary on a computer. You seem to think that binary consists in text containing '0' and '1' characters. That's not what binary means. a byte contained in a file is a sequence of 8 bits. A bit is a binary value. All files contain bytes, and are thus binary.